# I want to see a list of all tracked files in alphabetical order by git

Tags: git

I want to see a list of all tracked files in alphabetical order by git.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does `git ls-files` do what you want?

Comment: @Anton Kovalenko, you could add your comment as answer.

Comment: Great question! I was just looking for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git ls-files` lists all tracked files, and the order seems to be alphabetical as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sort command:

```
git ls-files | sort -d
```

The -d option sorts in alphabetical order.